# adding \n to uitextview with attributed string in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one issue by adding the \n to a uitextview with the attributed string, I am using the custom emoji's to be added to uitextview, so that I am doing with this

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];

attributedString = [_txtView.attributedText mutableCopy];

NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_arrEmojis objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];

textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:strName];

textAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -12, 44, 44);

NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

[attributedString insertAttributedString:attrStringWithImage atIndex:_txtView.selectedRange.location];

_txtView.attributedText = attributedString;

NSLog(@"%d",_txtView.attributedText.length);

_txtView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FontName size:FontSize];
```

Emoji is added in uitextview, but when I add \n with this code the textview's cursor stays at same level and when I re-add any custom emojis it is added at the end that is right, but not scrolling automatically up.

if anyone have the same issue, please reply.

Comment: Maybe you should change the bound of textAttachment when you add other text

Comment: Please try this code : `_txtView.attributedString = [attributedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];`

Comment: @Zakaria are you sure because I am getting error "no visible interface of nsmutableattributedstring declares the selector stringbyreplacyingoccurencesofstring"

Comment: Any one knows the solution ?